# CodeIgniter Calling a folder/index.php from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently using CodeIgniter 2.2 and I am getting the error message whenever I try running my test controller:

```
Unable to load the requested file: views/test/index.php
```

I want my controller to redirect me to index.php inside test folder under the views directory.

Inside my controller, I have:

```
<?php


class testControl extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $view_folder='views/test/';
        $data = '';
        $this->load->view($view_folder.'index', $data);
    }

}
```

In my application folder:

```
----controllers
     ---testControl
----views
     ---test
         --index.php
```

Here is my .htaccess which I putted inside the root directory (along with the default index file).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Am I missing anything? (Noted: My default welcome_page is working fine)

Comment: I think you did not read CI documentation http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291332/what-are-the-rules-followed-by-community-user-to-review-edit-suggestions. You don't need to write add `view` folder name when you call `$this->load->view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this-

```
public function index() {
    $view_folder='test/';
    $data = '';
    $this->load->view($view_folder.'index', $data);
}
```